# How to round to a certain amount of decimals while leaving a 0

Tags: python, rounding

see the list below:

```
2456905.204109
2456905.204132
2456905.204144
2456905.204155
2456905.204167
2456905.204178
2456905.20419
2456905.204201
2456905.204213
2456905.204225
```

The list goes on. I want to have the list all lined up so I want a `0` to the left of `2456905.204109`.

I am just using `x = round(num,6)`, but is there a way to always have 6 decimals? I haven't found anything other than other ways to round, which result in the same thing.

Comment: You can't force a number to have a unsignificant 0 more (because that doesn't work that way), however you can force the numbre of decimals you show when you print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string formatting

```
>>> '%0.6f' % 2456905.20410897654321
'2456905.204109'
>>> '%0.6f' % 2456905.20419
'2456905.204190'
```

Answer (score 0):

The number itself will not contain any insignificant digits as mentioned above, but you can alter the formatting when you print it. For instance you could write:

```
>>> x = round(2456905.20419, 6)
>>> '%0.6f' % x
```

Which will display as:

```
'2456905.204190'
```

Contrast this to just printing `x` without formatting, which will display as you are seeing right now:

```
2456905.20419
```

Comment: `'%0.6f'` will round the least significant digit. No need to `round` first.

Comment: @IceArdor In this case I'm including it because that's part of OP's code (possibly somewhere far away from printing), but that's a very good point.